# I'm trying to assign a 2-D array with a CSV file. When I try to print the first value in the 2-D array just for checking, it doesn't print anything

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like to know if the 2-D array is getting assigned properly, if yes, then why can't I echo it, and if no, then where am I going wrong?

```
    $ratings=array(array());
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
    $file_handle=fopen("C:/Users/Kartik Krishna Kumar/Desktop/Internship/Opinion comparison algo/userratings.csv","r");
    $i=0;
    while(($data=fgetcsv($file_handle,10000,","))!=FALSE){
        $n=count($data);
        for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
        {
            $ratings[$i][$j]=$data[$j];
        }               
        $i++;
    }
    echo $ratings[0][0];
    fclose($file_handle);
```

A person asked for the CSV file sample, I'm afraid I'm not able to provide it. But, I can tell you that it is a matrix (1000*10000) of numbers (range 1-10).
And the problem isn't an error, the problem is, nothing is getting printed and I have no idea why. I have checked for the existence of the file and am pretty sure the values are being passed.

Update:
Okay, now the ratings are getting stored inside the array, but not exactly how I wanted it to be. For some reason, only the first row is properly stored and after that any row I try to use has different values (mostly 0) compared to that of in the excel sheet. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your don't need to initialise the array with 2 dimensions just as an array is fine. Try using a foreach loop for accessing data array and do a `var_dump()` on your data array and ratings to see how it is structured. Post results of your var_dump()s if still need help

Comment: @Mike Miller, as you said I tried var_dump() on both my data array and ratings. It didn't print anything. I'm more than lost now.

Comment: However, this seems to be giving me an output.
'while(($data=fgetcsv($file_handle,10000,","))!=FALSE){
   $n=count($data);
   for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
   {
    $ratings[$i][$j]=$data[$j];
   }    
   $i++;
  }

Comment: Put your code and error with the line that is erroring and the message etc into your question its not easy to read in a comment. also show the contents of `$data` and `$ratings` using `var_dump()` or its not possible to understand whats wrong

Comment: When I tried using var_dump(), it did not give me an output, almost as if the array is missing. Sorry for the late reply, my internet was down.

Comment: Which array `$data` or `$ratings`?  f its empty then that is your problem - its empty. You can test using `if(empty($data)){echo 'its empty!'; }`. I have added an answer below to clear a few items up

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing only 0th element.

Replace `echo $ratings[0][0];` to `print_r($ratings);` to display full array.

Comment: As I said, I'm printing the first element just to test, pretty sure print_r($ratings); won't print anything as well. Edit:grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a load of debugging which should unpick it for you

```
$ratings=array();//you dont need to initialise as 2d
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$file_handle=fopen("C:/Users/Kartik Krishna Kumar/Desktop/Internship/Opinion comparison algo/userratings.csv","r");

//see if your handle is valid - should look like 'resource #12' if its good
var_dump($file_handle);

while(($data=fgetcsv($file_handle,10000,","))!=FALSE){
    //see if something is in the $data array first        
    var_dump($data);
    //a simpler version of your loop
    foreach($data as $key=>$row){
          //check your accesssing your $row ok
          var_dump($row);
          //add your $row item to your $ratings
          $ratings[$key]=$row; //you probably dont need to nest to 2 levels here or define a key if you are just using an arbitrary count
    }
}
var_dump($ratings);//see the whole thing

//you probably have an array in here so echo is no good
//echo $ratings[0][0]; 

//see the contents of the first index
var_dump($ratings[0]); //we removed a level

fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: The problem was for some reason, the usage of a while loop while getting the value from the file. I replaced it with a for loop and it worked like I wanted, not exactly, but at least it stored some data.